# SQL select syntax to compare list of values against sql table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have an excel with 3 columns. column1 lastname, column2 firstname, column3 fathername.
I exported these data from excel and make a list of data like this...
(Marley,Bob,George); (Jackson, Michael, Paul); (Connor, Sarah,Cathrine) etc.

In SQL (2008 r2), i have a table that has these 3 columns (and much more..).
I want to search if my table have persons exported from excel
I found a solution with repeatedly selects and union all at the end, but the rows i have is 5000 exported of excel against 70000 in sql table so i think that is not the best way with repeatedly unions.
So my question is if there is a syntax that is no need to repeat again and again the 
    select, and instead of this use something like

```
select lastname,firstname,fathername from table where ....
```

(Marley,Bob,George); 
(Jackson, Michael, Paul); 
(Connor, Sarah,Cathrine)

Thanks a lot for youur time,
Hercules

Comment: Can you show your full query? And expected results.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply. This is my first question in forum,so be patient with me.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply. This is my first question in forum,so be patient with me. i want to search which values of excel is in sql table. I've allready find myself a "solution"  but... For example i can write sql query like this    select lastname,firstname,fathername where lastname ='Marley' and firstname='bob' and fathername=George union all select lastname,firstname,fathername where lastname ='Jackson' and firstname='Michael' and fathername=Paul union all   and so on. But i have 5000 names to search,so i am asking if there is a way to write 1 time columns names and 1 line of each name

Answer (score 0):

use IN...

```
....
WHERE 
   lastname IN ('Marley','Jackson','Connor') 
   AND firstname ('Bob','Michael','Sarah')
....
```

However this will likely return unexpected results... because it doesn't associate paring. I.E. if someone is named "Sarah Marley" they would be returned. You may want to concatenate your names into a "Full Name" or use some other Key Field. Lastly, a better way would to load your FirstName, MiddleName, and LastName's into a #TempTable or @TableVariable and `INNER JOIN` them to your query, or use `WHERE EXISTS`